# Return generic Result<Foo<Bar>>

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class, that contains a result of type T or an error message. It has two convenience methods for creation:

```
public class Result<T> {

    private String errorMessage;
    private T result;

    ...

    public static <S> Result<S> ok(S body) {
        return new ServiceResult<S>(body);
    }

    public static <S> Result<S> error(String errorMessage, Class<S> clazz) {
        return new ServiceResult<S>(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

With the given methods I am able to create type save results of most types. The problem that I am facing now is that I am not able to create an error service result of a type that is itself generic.  Any help is very welcome!

To further specify the problem imagine I want to return results of type `List<String>`. If the result is successfully created I can create my result using the `ok()` method:

```
List<String> myStringList = ...;
Result<List<String>> result = Result.ok(myStringList);
```

If on the other hand an error occurred and I want to return an error result of the same type, then the provided method will not work, as it is not possible to create a `Class<List<String>>`:

```
// error, List<String>.class does not compile
Result<List<String>> result = Result.error("Error message", List<String>.class);
// error, result is of type Result<List>
Result<List<String>> result = Result.error("Error message", List.class);
```

Comment: One option is to cast `Result.error("Error message", List.class)` to the desired type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static <S> Result<S> error(String errorMessage, Class<S> clazz) {
    return new ServiceResult<S>(errorMessage);
}
```

This doesn't actually use `clazz`. So, remove the parameter, and you won't need to supply a value.

```
Result<List<String>> errorResult = error("whatever");
```

Comment: Nice, it works! Some explanation would be nice though. I thought I would need Class<S> clazz to define the type S. Do I understand correctly, that in this approach the type S is taken from whatever it is expected to be?

Comment: `S` is purely a compile-time thing. `Result<List<String>> foo` is just a `Result`, with an instruction to the compiler to automatically insert casts for `foo.result` (or `foo.getResult()`, or any other accessor which has type `T`) to make it a `List<String>` where it is used. There is no "S"-ness of the value to "take".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParameterizedTypeReference` instead of class itself.

In this case, you will be able to use

`Result.error("Error message", new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})`

instead of

`Result.error("Error message", List<String>.class);`

Comment: I think this is a Spring class. You can also use the TypeToken from Guava https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken